# Content deleted when reading file in java

Tags: java

I am writing a code that check if a number is a prime and if it is, print it in a file but when I open the InputStream, it automatically deleted the content in my file!
Here's my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class PrimeList {
public static void main(String[]args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    String name = "C:\\Text\\primelist.txt";
    File file = new File(name);
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
        BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(5);
        BigInteger zero = BigInteger.ZERO;
        BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
        while(true) {
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
            while(true) {
                BigInteger prime = BigInteger.valueOf(Long.parseLong(read.readLine()));
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Please show whole code of your program.

Comment: You are reading and writing on the same file...First read the file... Then create new file and append your result on that file.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are doing this

BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));

You are creating new FileInputStream(file) every time you call the method

Answer (score 2):

`new FileOutputStream(file, true)` should be used.
'true' means 'append'.